# Copying data from multiple non-sequential columns on multiple worksheets to one worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

The below is my current code in excel-VBA. I need to copy and paste values from multiple non-sequential columns on multiple worksheets into single columns on another worksheet. I am creating a report for aged payables (not important). I have 5 data sources or 5 tabs with raw data that need to be combined. For example: Sheet1 through Sheet5 have columns for invoice amount, country, and invoice date. They are completely different columns on each sheet. I need to move all the alike data into the same column on a separate worksheet. The below code is some elementary level copy and paste statements.

Is there a way to do the below operation in a single statement? How can I have the macro paste at the end of the data from each source? For example: if column A on sheet1 has 300 lines to copy and paste how can I get the next set of data to paste starting on row 301? The range is random from my sources, I could work with thousands of lines of data this month and hundreds the next month.

```
Sheets("RAW - Greenphire").Columns("Q").Copy
Sheets("RAW - Concatenated").Columns("A").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Sheets("RAW - Greenphire").Columns("O").Copy
Sheets("RAW - Concatenated").Columns("B").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Sheets("RAW - Greenphire").Columns("H").Copy
Sheets("RAW - Concatenated").Columns("C").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Sheets("RAW - Greenphire").Columns("J").Copy
Sheets("RAW - Concatenated").Columns("D").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Sheets("RAW - Greenphire").Columns("E").Copy
Sheets("RAW - Concatenated").Columns("E").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Sheets("RAW - Greenphire").Columns("A").Copy
Sheets("RAW - Concatenated").Columns("F").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Sheets("RAW - Greenphire").Columns("L").Copy
Sheets("RAW - Concatenated").Columns("G").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Sheets("RAW - Greenphire").Columns("K").Copy
Sheets("RAW - Concatenated").Columns("H").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Sheets("RAW - Greenphire").Columns("V").Copy
Sheets("RAW - Concatenated").Columns("I").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Sheets("RAW - Greenphire").Columns("W").Copy
Sheets("RAW - Concatenated").Columns("J").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Sheets("RAW - Greenphire").Columns("X").Copy
Sheets("RAW - Concatenated").Columns("K").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Sheets("RAW - Greenphire").Columns("Y").Copy
Sheets("RAW - Concatenated").Columns("L").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D4").Copy _ 
destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E5")
```

where you can calculate destiation range using using VBA